# local variable 'counter' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I am running the below code and getting this error.

I am used to c# syntax but this doesn't make any sense

The rest of the code is working i have tested. Only counter is the problem at the moment

[image]

```
import logging
from transformers import pipeline


counter = 1
#summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="csebuetnlp/mT5_multilingual_XLSum")

f = open("TextFile1.txt", "r")

ARTICLE = f.read()

#print(summarizer(ARTICLE, max_length=900, do_sample=False))

summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")

def summarize_text(text: str, max_len: int) -> str:
    try:
        #logging.warning("max_len " + str(max_len))
        summary = summarizer(text, max_length=max_len, min_length=100, do_sample=False)
        with open('parsed_'+str(counter)+'.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(text)
        counter += 1
        return summary[0]["summary_text"]
    except IndexError as ex:
        logging.warning("Sequence length too large for model, cutting text in half and calling again")
        return summarize_text(text=text[:(len(text) // 2)], max_len=max_len) +" "+ summarize_text(text=text[(len(text) // 2):], max_len=max_len)

gg = summarize_text(ARTICLE, 1024)

with open('summarized.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(gg)

[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing `counter` inside your function `summarize_text` and this is a global variable. By using `global counter`, you are stating that `counter` is a global variable, so when you change it, the interpreter knows you are changing the global variable and not a local variable to the function `summarize_text` called `counter`.

```py
...
counter = 1
...

def summarize_text(text: str, max_len: int) -> str:
    global counter
    ...
```

Btw, It is not a good practice to use global variables because it will make your code very hard to debug.

Comment: what you mean? yes i want to use global variable, increase it by 1 and use. how do i do that? I am using recursive method calls what else i could use?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what is the solution?

Comment: You need to use `global counter` to tell Python that counter is a global variable, so when you change `counter` it knows you are changing the global variable and not a local variable called `counter`

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG the solution **is in this answer**, and it is also in the linked duplicate above. BTW, you would have found many similar duplicates by just *googling the error message*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga still not working : https://i.imgur.com/G8eaSVI.png any ideas?

Comment: lmiguelvargasf I tested your method and if i use that how do i set initial value?

Comment: you set it at the top of the code `counter = 1`, you just need to add that line, and it should work.

Comment: lmiguelvargasf   please check these 2 : https://i.imgur.com/G8eaSVI.png  https://i.imgur.com/hRHHZeW.png

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, you should add that line inside the function not outside.

Comment: very weird logic but finally works ty. this is why I love c# :)

Comment: lmiguelvargasf how would you do it in this case without using global variable? it is a recursive function

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  the answer marked as answer in the duplicate doesn't explain anything

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG it explains *everything*, actually. It explains *why* the error occurs and the solution.

Comment: Anyway, to avoid global variables, generally you either 1) use arguments/return values 2) use a class to encapsulate state

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the answer of lmiguelvargasf explains much better. those 2 method looks good solution in this case.